# Apply different group of filters to HTML column with yadcf (datatables)

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I have a datatables column created in HTML (image) with this format:

```
<img src='[path to image]' class='[imgClass]'>
```

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgutbor/0566dbvv/) to see it in action.

Here is the conditions:

- I have four images: black, green, yellow and red.
- And I have two possible status: assigned/not assigned.
- Black image belongs to not assigned status and green, yellow and red to assigned status.

To filter the images on column header, i search for the class and it works ok. But when i press ASSIGNED button on top(to get red, yellow and green ones), the filter doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to do a multi select filtering while your filter type was a *single select*

So you should set your yadcf filter to `filter_type: 'multi_select',` - [see jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0566dbvv/30/)

or even better use *select2* with *yadcf* like this (select2 css/js should be added)

`filter_type: 'multi_select',
 select_type: 'select2',`

[see jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0566dbvv/32/)

Comment: Really thanks for your help, Daniel. It's works again.